# Lemma 3.3 in the book of the Fanghua Lin

Tags: sobolev-spaces, estimation

> **Lemma 3.3** Suppose $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ satisfies
>   $$\int_{B_r(x_0)}|Du|^2 \le M r^{^\mu} \quad \mbox{for any} \ \ B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega,$$
>   for some $\mu \in [0,n)$. Then, for any $\Omega' \Subset \Omega$ there holds for any $B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega$ with $x_0 \in \Omega'$
>   $$\int_{B_r(x_0)} |u|^2 \le C(n,\lambda,\mu,\Omega,\Omega')\, \left \{M+\int_{\Omega}u^2\right \} r^{\lambda}$$
>   where $\lambda = \mu +2$ if $\mu < n-2$ and $\lambda$ is any number in $[0,n)$ if $n-2\le\mu<n$.

**Proof.** Denote $R_0= \mbox{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$. For any $x_0 \in \Omega'$  and $0<r\le R_0$, the Poincaré inequality yields
$$\int_{B_r(x_0)}|u- u_{x_0,r}|\le cr^2 \int_{B_r(x_0)}|du|^2 \le c(n)Mr^{\mu +2}.$$
And this implies that
$$\int_{B_r(x_0)}|u- u_{x_0,r}| \le c(n)Mr^{\lambda}.$$
where $\lambda$ as in the lemma 3.3.

Then, following the proof, I understand the case $\lambda = \mu +2$ if $\mu < n-2$. But I don't understand how to obtain the case $\lambda$ is any number in $[0,n)$ if $n-2\le\mu<n$?

Comment: You don't understand why the inequality after "implies that" is true in the case $n-2\leq\mu<n$? Or are you talking about another part of the proof that is not displayed here?

Comment: I don't know if $$\int_{B_r(x_0)}|u- u_{x_0,r}|\le cr^2 \int_{B_r(x_0)}|du|^2 \le c(n)Mr^{\mu +2}.$$
 implies that $$\int_{B_r(x_0)}|u- u_{x_0,r}| \le c(n)Mr^{\lambda}.$$ where $\lambda$ is any number in $[0,n)$ if $n-2\le\mu<n$. Seems that the author proof the two cases in the same way after this. He did not write another part.

Comment: Suppose for a moment that $R_0<1$. Then $n-2\leq \mu <n$ means $n \leq \mu+2 <n+2$, and thus $\lambda < \mu+2$. But $r^{\mu+2} < r^\lambda$ for $0 \leq r <1$. Can you treat now the case $r \leq R_0$ for any $R_0$?

Comment: I had thought of that. No, I can not.

Comment: Of course, it will imply, because $\lambda\leq\mu+2$ in either case.

Comment: But if $\lambda \le \mu +2$ and $r\ge 1$ we have $r^{\mu+2} \not\leq r^\lambda$.

Comment: Well, that can be absorbed into the constant, since $r\leq R_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The second part goes into the first part, if n is shiftet up, to the right or whatever, by two. The fixed value is $\mu$, not $n$.So for the case $n-2 ≤ \mu < n$, use $n' = n+2$, then $\mu < n = n+2-2 = n'-2$. 
Get
 $$ \int_{B_r(x_0)} |u|^2 \leq C(n',\lambda,\mu,\Omega,\Omega') \left\{ M+\int_\Omega u^2 \right\}r^{\lambda} $$ 
where $\lambda =\mu+2$    and use $\left(\frac{R_0}{r}\right)^{\lambda} ≤ \left(\frac{R_0}{r}\right)^{\mu + 2}$ or  $\quad$   $r^{\mu+2} ≤ R_0^{\mu + 2 - \lambda} r^\lambda$ because $\lambda \mapsto x^\lambda $ is non-increasing for $x \leq 1$.

Comment: Sorry, but did not understand.

Comment: If $\mu \in [0, n)$ then also $\mu \in [0, n'=n+2)$